# Getting Undefined Method "Error" in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am creating a survey tool with Rails. I am trying to set up validation for the Answer where the participant has to submit an answer that is longer than 5 characters. I am getting the following error when I try to add a new answer.

> undefined method `errors'

I have read in other posts that it is likely to be caused because you haven't initialised the answer object in the answers controller. My problem with this is that I have - it just doesn't look like this:

```
def new
  @answer = Answer.new
end
```

It looks like this in my code:

```
  def new
    @study = Study.find(params[:study_id])
    @question = @study.questions.find(params[:question_id])
    @participant = find_participant
    @answer = @question.answers.build(participant: @participant)
  end
```

This is the code for my Answer Model:

```
class Answer < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :participant
  validates :answer, presence: true,
            length: { minimum: 5 }
end
```

And this is the full error that I am getting in my server:

```
Started GET "/studies/32/questions/63/answers/new" for ::1 at 2020-02-18 10:14:41 +1300
   (2.1ms)  SELECT sqlite_version(*)
Processing by AnswersController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"study_id"=>"32", "question_id"=>"63"}
  Study Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "studies".* FROM "studies" WHERE "studies"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 32], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/answers_controller.rb:3:in `new'
  Question Load (1.5ms)  SELECT "questions".* FROM "questions" WHERE "questions"."study_id" = ? AND "questions"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["study_id", 32], ["id", 63], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/answers_controller.rb:4:in `new'
   (0.5ms)  begin transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/answers_controller.rb:33:in `find_participant'
  Participant Create (4.5ms)  INSERT INTO "participants" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)  [["created_at", "2020-02-17 21:14:45.571329"], ["updated_at", "2020-02-17 21:14:45.571329"]]
  ↳ app/controllers/answers_controller.rb:33:in `find_participant'
   (3.0ms)  commit transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/answers_controller.rb:33:in `find_participant'
  Rendering answers/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Answer Load (1.5ms)  SELECT "answers".* FROM "answers" WHERE "answers"."question_id" = ?  [["question_id", 63]]
  Rendered answers/new.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 1228.1ms | Allocations: 13885323)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4106ms (ActiveRecord: 12.0ms | Allocations: 37401284)



ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `errors' for #<Answer::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x00007fae2e5792f0>):
    4:   <%= form_with model: @answer, url: study_question_answers_path(@study, @question), local: true do |form| %>
    5:     <%= form.hidden_field :participant_id %>
    6:    
    7:     <% if @question.answers.errors.any? %>
    8:      
    9:       
   10:     <% end %>
```

This is my first rails project and I'm not sure what I'm missing - can anyone help me out here?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the answer model code?

Comment: I have added the code to the question above!

Comment: The stack trace should tell you exactly where the error is being raised. If you can't read it or find the line that actually points to your code you can add the whole thing to your question. `undefined method 'errors'` is just the error message of the exception and does not tell us anything since NoMethodError is extremely common and is usually caused by typos or a lack of nil checking. There is nothing obviously wrong with the code here so we need that stack trace.

Comment: Right, of course! I have added some more detail of what is happening in my server, I hope this helps/is what you meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `@question.answers` is a collection of multiple objects.  You can't just call `.errors` on that.  You will have to either loop through the objects and call errors on each,

```
<% @question.answers.each do |answer| %>
  <% if answer.errors.any? %>

  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

or, what I think you want to do from looking at the view file, is call that on the specific `@answer` variable for the form.

```
<% if @answer.errors.any? %>
```

Answer (score -1):

The Solution provided by @RockwellRice is correct and I briefed it for better understanding below

`answers` is a collection and not a single object. Iterate through them and then call errors on a single answer instance

```
<% @question.answers.each do |ans| %>
    <% if ans.errors.any? %>

    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

or if you want to handle an error on a specific answer record
then you can modify that line

```
from 
<% @question.answers.errors.any? %>
to 
<% @question.answers[0].errors.any? %>
```

here you can refer to specific answer through array index and then can access its errors info

Comment: but calling it on the first in the array won't necissarily call it on the correct one will it?

Comment: Thanks for expanding Ganeshkumar - if @RockwellRice's answer helped, it's a good convention to accept it via the green tick next to the answer :)

Comment: Thank you for expanding on this for me!